# Extract First Column from a Dataframe in R, Having NA

Tags: r, plot

I have a scenario Where i need to plot a graph accordingly with the help of date column and the last column namely 'closed', but i cant extract the date column as the column name is 'null'

```
  head(data,5)
              FCEL.BO.Open FCEL.BO.High FCEL.BO.Low FCEL.BO.Close FCEL.BO.Volume Closed
 2011-05-12         8.60         8.75        8.35          8.45        2527300   8.45
 2011-05-13         8.45         9.30        8.25          8.90        7110100   8.90
 2011-05-16         8.90         9.15        8.60          8.80        3635800   8.80
 2011-05-17         8.65         8.85        8.50          8.50        1056300   8.50
 2011-05-18         9.20         9.20        8.25          8.30        1188000   8.30
```

i Have taken only 5 rows for showing,

```
  plot(as.Date(data$?, "%d-%b-%y"),data$Closed, xlab = "Dates", ylab = "Adjusted closing price", 
 type = "l", col = "red", main = "Adjusted closing price")
```

What should i write in the place of "?".

Comment: This column is probably not a column but the rownames. Try `rownames(data)`. If that works, you can make it a column using `data$Date <- rownames(data)`.

Comment: @Molx the Result is NULL

Comment: What's the result of `names(data)`?

Comment: '[1] "FCEL.BO.Open"   "FCEL.BO.High"   "FCEL.BO.Low"    "FCEL.BO.Close"  "FCEL.BO.Volume"
[6] "Closed"'

Comment: That doesn't agree with the data you posted. Where's `Closed`? Can you add the result of `dput(head(data))` to the question, please?

Comment: @Molx `Closed` is the last column. However, what's the output of `str(data)`?

Comment: An ‘xts’ object on 2011-05-12/2015-07-17 containing:
  Data: num [1:1085, 1:6] 8.6 8.45 8.9 8.65 9.2 8.5 8.15 8.25 8.2 8 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "FCEL.BO.Open" "FCEL.BO.High" "FCEL.BO.Low" "FCEL.BO.Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ src    : chr "yahoo"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2015-07-20 17:50:34"

Comment: To see the dates use: `index(data)`

Comment: @nicola he edited the comment. Anyway, without the actual data it's hard to understand what's going on. Please add the result of `dput()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
library(quantmod)
plot(Cl(data), xlab = "Dates", ylab = "Adjusted closing price", 
     type = "l",  main = "Adjusted closing price")
```

Or

```
plot(as.Date(index(data), "%d-%b-%y"), Cl(data), ylab = "Adjusted Closed",
     xlab = "Date", type = "l", col = "red", main = "Adjusted closing price")
```

[image]

Comment: Error in plot(Ad(data), xlab = "Dates", ylab = "Adjusted closing price",  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': Error in Ad(data) : 
  subscript out of bounds: no column name containing "Adjusted"

Comment: `plot(as.Date(index(data), "%d-%b-%y"), data$Closed, xlab = "Adjusted Closed", ylab = "Date", 
     type = "l", col = "red", main = "Adjusted closing price ")`
This is Working @Robert

Comment: The above code is throwing error,
'plot': Error in Ad(data) :
The quantmod is present

Comment: Actually No,its Showing values more than the value which are present in the data$Closed. Its just a diagonal line,Seems to be not correct

Comment: Can u pls tell where i should use that `Cl` in the code instead of Adjusted